# Visual studio debugger tooltip information

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In visual studio, I believe there was a way to define what information to show on the tooltip when you roll over your mouse to a particular variable (or location) inside your code during debug mode. I can't quite remember what it was, something like [DebuggerInformation] but I might be wrong.

What is the functionality called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) to do that.